# Mongoose pre-update document middleware - changed field is not written to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongoose version 5.13.15

I am trying to set the value of fields (updatedBy, createdBy) on a document whenever it is written (created/updated).

As part of this endeavor, I have created the following test code to try to get it working

```
let currentUserId = '1';

const sampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  color: String,
  createdBy: String,
  updatedBy: String,
});

sampleSchema.pre('save', async function() {
  console.log('save middleware called. This constructor:', this.constructor.name);
  let modifiedById = currentUserId;
  if (this.isNew) {
    this.createdBy = modifiedById;
  }
  this.updatedBy = modifiedById;
});

sampleSchema.pre('updateOne', {document: true, query: false}, async function() {
  console.log('updateOne middleware called. This constructor:', this.constructor.name);
  console.log('Setting `updatedBy` to ', currentUserId);
  this.updatedBy = currentUserId;
});

SampleModel = mongoose.model('sample', sampleSchema)

// Create
let sampleA = new SampleModel({color: 'black'});
let saved = await sampleA.save();
console.log('saved', saved);

// updateOne
currentUserId = '4';
await saved.updateOne({color: 'green'});
saved = await SampleModel.findOne({_id: saved._id});
console.log('saved 2', saved);
```

The output is as follows:

```txt
save middleware called. This constructor: model
saved {
  _id: 641cc720863a8421476a16ca,
  color: 'black',
  createdBy: '1',
  updatedBy: '1',
  __v: 0
}
updateOne middleware called. This constructor: model
Setting `updatedBy` to  4
saved 2 {
  _id: 641cc720863a8421476a16ca,
  color: 'green',
  createdBy: '1',
  updatedBy: '1',
  __v: 0
}
```

The output demonstrates that updateOne middleware is being called and the `currentUserId` value is as expected. The update sets the color field as expected to `green` but the `updatedBy` field remains unchanged. It should have been set to 4.

How do I set the value of a document field in the updateOne pre-save middleware?

Edit:

n.b. I am using the document middleware, not the query middleware (as configured by the 2nd argument `{document: true, query: false}`). In such a case, `this` refers to the mongoose document (as can be seen in the output where the constructor name is `model` - a mongoose document is an instance of a mongoose model). This method of configuring middleware for the document is described in the mongoose middleware documentation.

Comment: Have you tried it using `next()`? In 5.x you should be able to drop that, but I'm curious to see if it makes a difference regardless.

Comment: Yes, I've tried removing async and calling next(). Same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `await saved.updateOne({color: 'green'});` saved is an object and updateOne is a Mongoose operation.

I just modified your code and optimize the query. See the examples here:

**For create:**
rest of the code is the same, I just created a function for easiness.

```
// Create
let saved;
async function saveFunc() {

  saved = await SampleModel.create({color: 'black'});
  console.log('saved', saved);
  return saved;
}
```

Output:

```
 save middleware called. This constructor: { color: 'black', _id: new 
 ObjectId("641ea7465dfaaaee0e250caa") }
 modifiedById:  1
 saved {
  color: 'black',
  _id: new ObjectId("641ea7465dfaaaee0e250caa"),
  createdBy: '1',
  updatedBy: '1',
  __v: 0
 }
```

[image]

**For Update:**

code:

```
// updateOne
async function updateFunc(saved) {
  currentUserId = '4';
  saved = await SampleModel.updateOne({_id: saved._id},{color: 'green'});
  console.log('saved 2', saved);
}
```

Output:

```
updateOne middleware called. This constructor: Query
Setting `updatedBy` to  4
currentUserId:  4
saved 2 {
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

**NOTE:** `updateOne()` always return acknowledgement not a document. If you want to return updated document then use `findOneAndUpdate()` with `{new: true}` as 3rd params.

[image]
**NOTE:** There are 2 documents 1st for only create and 2nd for create and update.

Function calling:

```
saveFunc().then((resp) => {
  updateFunc(resp)
});
```

Comment: `save()` returns a mongoose document object, not a pojo, if that's what you mean. I CAN call `saved.updateOne` - I do so in the code sample I've shown and that code sample works and outputs the output you see in my question. The pojos you see in the output are of course the `toString()` representation of the mongoose document objects they represent - not the actual value. Your answer suggests I switch from using Document.updateOne to Query.updateOne - but my question is explicitly about Document,updateOne.

Comment: @JoelHarris I got your question. You just need to change the line in `updateOne()` pre-hook.

From `this.updatedBy = currentUserId;` to `  this._update.updatedBy = currentUserId;`

everything else will be same because when you use update pre-hook, data that need to update is passed in `_update` object. And finding portion is passed in `_conditions` object. For more ref, visit the [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)